# How to set minimum width in Apache POI cell?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writing a tool in Java, using Apache POI API to convert an XML to MS Excel. I want to set the minimum cell width to 100 px.

How to set the custom width in the cell?

Comment: Which format? HSSF or XSSF?

Answer (score 1):

I have used simply this function `sheet.setColumnWidth(colIdx, width*256)` to set column width, my application uses 1...n value scale and *256 is something which had to be done to see good result.

This example code lists imports, I am (probably) using SXSSF serialized writer but POI documentation is a bit hard to understand all differences. This example opens a base xlsx file first, then I write values to the Data sheet. Base file has few chart and sheets I made in Excel and does not want to recreate in POI.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;
//import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
//import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;

  public void doIt() {
        OPCPackage opc =  OPCPackage.open(file);
        XSSFWorkbook xwb = new XSSFWorkbook(opc); // (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(file);        
        SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(xwb, 500); //XSSFWorkbook wb = xwb;
        ...clip....do something...
        try { wb.dispose(); } catch (Exception e) { }
        try { opc.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
```